# Power Query: Combine Subset of List of Tables that Exist

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

I have a Power Query whose first step is to combine a set of tables:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({One_foo_bar, Two_foo_bar, Three_foo_bar, Four_foo_bar, Five_foo_bar, Six_foo_bar, Seven_foo_bar, Eight_foo_bar}),
    // ...
    #"Result" = ...
in
    #"Result"
```

The problem is that not all of the named tables may exist. Any subset of the tables may exist. Those that do exist are in `ThisWorkbook`. If any are missing, the M code shown above will throw an error.

If pattern matching can help solve this problem, the table names all follow the pattern ***_foo_bar**. M does not seem to have support for this type of pattern matching, but I include this statement in case anybody knows something I don't and could utilize this fact to formulate a solution.

How may I modify this code to combine the tables that do exist?

Comment: Where are these tables coming from? An Excel Workbook? Multiple workbooks that are Open? Stored in a Folder? etc. It should be fairly straightforward to filter that list to meet your requirements.

Comment: Ron, thank you for the clarifying question. At this point, I have arrived at an answer, but nonetheless, I have edited my original post to answer your question so that this post is a clearer reference in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` as the Source, then filter the Name column to return only the items that end with "_foo_bar". For example,

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.EndsWith([Name], "_foo_bar")),
    #"Combine Tables" = Table.Combine(#"Filtered Rows"[Content])
in
    #"Combine Tables"
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and this is not a full answer, but I would start with this idea. First, build the array of existing tables in excel like:

[image]

then using power query to get the existing tables from that table.

An alternative is to build that array more directly in PowerQuery using `TRY`

Answer (score 0):

Although I have accepted the answer given by @DjC, I'll post for future reference an answer I arrived at using the suggestion given by @gns100.

```
let
    remove_errors_f = (input_list as list) as list =>
                          List.RemoveNulls(
                                              List.Transform(
                                                                List.Positions(input_list),
                                                                each try input_list{_} otherwise null
                                                            )
                                          ),

    #"MyTables" = remove_errors_f({One_foo_bar, Two_foo_bar, Three_foo_bar, Four_foo_bar, Five_foo_bar, Six_foo_bar, Seven_foo_bar, Eight_foo_bar}),
    #"Column Names" = {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"},

    combiner_f = (AccumulatedTable as table, TablesToCombine as list) as table =>
                 if List.Count(TablesToCombine) = 0 then
                     AccumulatedTable
                 else
                     @combiner_f(Table.Combine({AccumulatedTable, TablesToCombine{0}}), List.RemoveFirstN(TablesToCombine, 1)),

    Source = combiner_f(#table(#"Column Names", {}), #"MyTables"),
    // ...
    #"Result" = ...
in
    #"Result"
```